# function call in PHP or JS

Tags: php, javascript

Actually I want to validate username nd password only for my `os1 == 2` which is linux so please help me

```
if (os1 == 1) os = "Windows";

if (os1 == 2) os = "Linux";
if (os1 == 3) os = "Others";


function Validate() {

var dropdownIndex = document.getElementById('type').selectedIndex;
var sztype = document.getElementById('type')[dropdownIndex].value;

if (sztype == "1") {
    var szpassword = "";
    var szguid = "";
    var name = Trim(document.userform.name.value);

    var ip = Trim(document.userform.ip.value);
    if (ip.length == 0) {
        alert("Please specify IP/Host Name.");
        return false;
    }
    if (name.length == 0) {
        name = ip;
    }

    szusername = Trim(document.userform.username.value);

    if (szusername.length == 0) {
        alert("Please specify Username.");
        return false;
    }

    var szvalidchars = new RegExp("[~!@#$%^&*()+|{}:\"<>?,/;'=\\`]");
    if (szvalidchars.test(szusername)) {
        alert("Username cannot contain invalid characters.");
        return false;
    }

    szpassword = Trim(document.userform.password.value);
    if (szpassword.length == 0) {
        alert("Please specify Password.");
        return false;
    }
```

and I have a table like this

```
<form name="userform">
<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
<tr>
    <td><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td style="padding-left:12px; padding-top:10px;  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">To add single/multipe physical server(s), enter the IP address/range of physical server(s).</td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></br>
    <table border=0> 
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:20px; padding-top:5px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">Type: </td>
        <td style="padding-top:5px; padding-left:50px;">
        <select name="type" id="type" class="SelectList Width200" onchange="OnCbTpyeChange()">
        <?php
        foreach($type as $key => $value)
        {
            echo  "<option value=\"".$key."\"";
            echo">";
            echo $value;
            echo "</option>";
        }
        ?>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="hostname_table" name="hostname_table" border=0>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:20px; padding-top:10px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">Name: </td>
        <td style="padding-top:10px;">
        <input name="name" type="text" maxlength="50" >
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:20px; padding-top:10px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">IP/Host Name: </td>
        <td style="padding-top:10px;">
        <input name="ip" type="text" maxlength="50" >
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:20px; padding-top:10px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">User Name: </td>
        <td style="padding-top:10px;">
        <input name="username" type="text" maxlength="50" >
        </td>

    <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:20px; padding-top:10px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">Password: </td>
        <td style="padding-top:10px;">
        <input type="password" name="password" type="text" maxlength="50">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:20px; padding-top:10px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">OS: </td>
        <td style="padding-top:10px;">
        <select name="os" id="os" class="SelectList Width200">
        <?php
        foreach($ostype as $key => $value)
        {
            echo  "<option value=\"".$key."\"";

            echo">";
            echo $value;
            echo "</option>";
        }
        ?>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="nwrange_table" name="nwrange_table" style="display:none">

        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:20px; padding-top:10px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">Start IP Address: </td>
            <td style="padding-top:10px;">
            <input name="startip" type="text" maxlength="50" id='startip'>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:20px; padding-top:10px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">End IP Address: </td>
            <td style="padding-top:10px;">
            <input name="endip" type="text" maxlength="50" id='endip'>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: write a onchange event for the select box and in that call a function and in that function check if the selected value is linux or not... Very simple

Comment: It is very unclear what your question is. What do you expect to happen and what is actually happening??

Comment: What does this function do: `OnCbTpyeChange()`? Do you even have it?

Comment: function OnCbTpyeChange()
{
 var dropdownIndex = document.getElementById('type').selectedIndex;
 var sztype = document.getElementById('type')[dropdownIndex].value;
 if(sztype == "1")
 {
  document.getElementById('nwrange_table').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('hostname_table').style.display = "block";
 }
 else if(sztype == "2")
 {
  document.getElementById('hostname_table').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('nwrange_table').style.display = "block";
 }

}

Comment: So, can you explain what's not working? What do you expect to happen that doesn't happen? E.g. are you getting javascript errors? The validation doesn't work at all? The validtions works for Windows, instead of for Linux? In other words: what is the problem??

Also it maybe helpful to show the contents of the php variable `$type`.

Comment: i only want when user select OS - linux ... then function call otherwise if user select OS - window no need to call this function validate()
i think it requires if condition in function Validate() .... can u ans me how it is posible to put if condition in function validate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function Validate()
{
    var dropdownIndex = document.getElementById('type').selectedIndex;
    var sztype = document.getElementById('type')[dropdownIndex].value;

    if(sztype == "1")
    {
        //var os1 = userform.os.selectedIndex;
        var dropdownosIndex = document.getElementById('os').selectedIndex;
        var os1 = document.getElementById('os')[dropdownosIndex].value;

        if (os1 == 1)
            os = "Windows";

        if (os1 == 2)
            os = "Linux";

        if (os1 == 3)
            os = "Others";

        var ip = Trim(document.userform.ip.value);
        szusername = Trim(document.userform.username.value);
        szpassword = Trim(document.userform.password.value);

        if(os != 'Linux')
        {
            if(ip.length == 0)
            {
                alert("Please specify IP/Host Name.");
                return false;
            }
            if(name.length == 0)
            {
                name=ip;
            }

            if(szusername.length == 0)
            {
                alert("Please specify Username.");
                return false;
            }

            var szvalidchars = new RegExp("[~!@#$%^&*()+|{}:\"<>?,/;'=\\`]");
            if(szvalidchars.test(szusername))
            {
                alert("Username cannot contain invalid characters.");
                return false;
            }

            if(szpassword.length == 0)
            {
                alert("Please specify Password.");
                return false;
            }
        }

        var szpassword = "";
        var szguid = "";
        var name = Trim(document.userform.name.value);

        var hostid = "Physical";
        szHostName = hostid;
        szname = name;
        var os = "Others";

        params = "guid="+szguid+"&username="+szusername+"&password="+szpassword+"&ip="+ip+"&name="+name+"&os="+os ;
        //alert(params);
        document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';//change cursor to wait

        if(!http)
            http = CreateObject();

        nocache = Math.random();

        http.open('post', 'addvm.php');
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
        http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        http.onreadystatechange = SaveReply;

        http.send(params);
    }

    // Etc...
```

Comment: You expect people to help you by just pointing them to huge blocks of unreadable code. It seems you yourself have no idea what that code is doing. I have lost the will to help you, so if my latest update doesn't do what you want you will have to ask someone else. And please read the FAQ before you ask a question again: http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Comment: i have done it .... Thanks for ur ful coperation ..i wil kept in my mind such things ... ches ...

Comment: You are welcome. To show other users that your question has been answered, you can click the "V" sign next to the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not *exactly* sure what problem you are asking for help with, but here are some observations:

- Your Javascript is code is trying to get the data from an HTML entity with ID "type", but I don't see such an entity in the code you provided. There is a select box called "os", but nothing called "type". You'd probably get a Javascript error from that.
- Your password field has two types (password and text)...that's probably not what you are asking about, but it's something that should be fixed.
- Doing client-side only (without server-side validation) is always a bad idea, since people can just disable Javascript to bypass it.
- It looks like the code only wants to do validation for `sztype == 1`, which I assume is Windows, though it's impossible to tell without seeing the contents of `$ostype`. Do you still need help validating other OS types? How does validation need to differ between OSes?

Sorry for a non-specific answer...it wasn't a terribly specific question.

Comment: See i have an table as shown as above 
now i have an option Select OS-operating system in this :)
now i want if user select OS Linux then function call  and if user select windows no need to call function kkkkk
OS:<select name="os" id="os" class="SelectList Width200">
</select>

Comment: this is not my whole coding i declare everything in my coding .

Comment: For Javascript, it sounds like you'll need to add an `onsubmit` event to your form that calls the `Validate()` function. If it validates correctly, it should return true. Otherwise, false. I'm not sure if you already have that, though, since it's not included in the above code.

Comment: ya i already have <input  type = "button" value = "OK" id = "ok" class="FormButton" onclick="Validate();"/>

Comment: So then what is the problem? Did you fix the problem I noted above in that there is no HTML element with an ID of "type"?